# Datagridview Auto Reording after Add/ Remove

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, addition, datagridviewcolumn

I'm using a vb.net datagridview table for displaying several different types of data. When I need to load new data, I remove the rows and then remove the columns of the current data and then add the columns and rows of the new data. However, when I reload data that has previously been displayed (removed and now re-added), the columns are in a different order, for example, on load the order is col1 then col2 (which is the order I want) and after remove and add it is col2 then col1. Below is an example of the code:

```
Dim mycol1 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn
Dim mycol2 As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn

    With mycol1
        .Name = "col1"
        .HeaderText = "col1"
        .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        .MaxInputLength = 4
        .DisplayIndex = 0
    End With

    With mycol2
        .Name = "col2"
        .HeaderText = "col2"
        .SortMode = DataGridViewColumnSortMode.NotSortable
        .MaxInputLength =
        .DisplayIndex = 1
    End With

Private Sub form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

dgv.Columns.Add(col1)
dgv.Columns.Add(col2)
   a = 0
   Do While a < 10
   dgv.Rows.Add()
   a += 1
Loop

End Sub

Private Sub button1_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
   a = 0
   Do While a < me.dgv.rows.count
   dgv.Rows.remove()
   a += 1
Loop

dgv.Columns.remove(col1)
dgv.Columns.remove(col2)

End Sub

Private Sub button2_click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
dgv.Columns.Add(col1)
dgv.Columns.Add(col2)
a = 0
   Do While a < 10
   dgv.Rows.Add()
   a += 1
Loop

End Sub
```

Does anybody know what is causing the reordering?

Comment: while col1 has .DisplayIndex = 0  I think is very strange to show col2 before .. AND other ideea for deleting rows an columns you don't need fro, loos .. etc Just USE: dgv.Rows.Clear() .... and  dgv.Columns.Clear()

Comment: Thanks Cristi for your response. I found that the index is still correct, just the displayindex is incorrect, I'm thinking it has to do with the order I remove the columns, for example, if I remove col1 first, col2 is now display index 1, and when it reloads, col2 stays as displayindex1. On reload, I've now added code to reassign the display index, and it seems to be working.

As for your suggestion on rows.clear() and columns.clear(), this has become very handy and has sacrificed a lot of my code, thank you for that suggestion.

Comment: welcome :) cick the arrow ^ :)